# Exporting multiple line code without changes using echo / linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed, echo, centos7

System CentOS 7.2
Looking for a solution to write multi line code to a file without changes

small piece form a code:

```
echo '
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '46s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '47s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'48 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
' >> output.sh
```

Desired output:

```
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '46s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '47s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'48 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
```

What I'm getting is :

```
sed -i $45 a n /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $45 a n /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $45 a n /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i 46s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg# /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i 47s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg# /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $48 a n /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
```

as you can see Quotes are disappearing, no matter I'm using single quote or double quote with echo. may be there is an other solution than ECHO or some sort of universal brackets to keep code unchanged when writing to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat <<EOF >> output.sh
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '46s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '47s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'48 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
EOF
```

Comment: Dos not works for script like :  yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
bel=$(tput bel)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
reset=$(tput sgr0)   but this part I suppose can be exported using echo and the rest using EOF,  Thanks

Comment: @Wice22 Whatever it is you mean by that statement, using a mixture of echo and a here doc is not the right approach. Post a new question if you'd like help.