# Creating an output file with multi line script without any changes using bash / linux

Tags: bash, sed, output, echo, centos7

System CentOS 7.2, Looking for a solution to create output file from multi line code,  without changes
Please note echo"" with double quotes is not working too.

small piece form a code:

```
echo '
yellow=`tput setaf 3`
bel=`tput bel`
red=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0
echo"#${green}Installing packages${reset}#" &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '46s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '47s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'48 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg 
' >> output
```

Desired output

```
yellow=`tput setaf 3`
bel=`tput bel`
red=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0
echo"#${green}Installing packages${reset}#" &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '46s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '47s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'48 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

What I'm getting if I use echo:

```
yellow=`tput setaf 3`
bel=`tput bel`
red=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0
echo"#${green}Installing packages${reset}#" &&
sed -i $45 a n /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $45 a n /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $45 a n /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i 46s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg# /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i 47s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg# /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $48 a n /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
```

***Quotes are disappearing***

What I'm getting if I use EOF

```
yellow=^[[33m
bel=^G
red=^[[31m
green=^[[32m
reset=^[(B^[[m
echo"#${green}Installing packages${reset}#" &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '46s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '47s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'48 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
```

As you can see non of them works as an universal solution, and I think combining them is not a right way to do it...

Comment: Use quoted EOF, as documented in `man bash`, or replace single quotes with `'\''` in the first snippet.

Comment: exactly the same homework as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711252/exporting-multiple-line-code-without-changes-using-echo-linux/40711277

Comment: wrt `if I use EOF` - you are talking about using a [here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). The text `EOF` as the delimiter is arbitrary. Saying `if I use EOF` would be meaningless without the context of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711252/exporting-multiple-line-code-without-changes-using-echo-linux/40711277). Why are you using 2 different login names, btw?

Comment: Did you mean to have an unmatched backtick on the line starting `reset=`?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, in any way, enclose a single quote inside a single-quoted string. The simplest thing to do here is to replace `echo` with `cat` and a here-document.

```
cat <<'EOF' >> output
yellow=`tput setaf 3`
bel=`tput bel`
red=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0
echo"#${green}Installing packages${reset}#" &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'45 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '46s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i '47s#.*#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg#' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg &&
sed -i $'48 a \n' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg 
EOF
```

The quoted delimiter causes the contents to be treated *as if* it were a quoted string, without having to worry about the syntax of quoted strings.

Otherwise, you would need to use a `$'...'` string and be sure to escape any enclosed single quotes and backslashes.

```
echo $'
...
sed -i $\'45 a \\n\' ...
...
'
```

Yuck.